# How to get installed version of Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable(x64) in mfc application

Tags: c++, mfc

I working on mfc application in which I need to check currently installed version Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable.
Is there any way?

Comment: Just add the redist package you require to your installer. Or build a static version of the application so that you don't need the redistributables.

Comment: What are you going to do with this information? It's not even helpful for diagnostics. If you need to know this information, you have failed to produce a proper application deployment (including all dependencies).

Answer (score 0):

Each VS Version has its own redistributable files and they are named with a version number in the name.

So there is no "current" version. There may be several installations for different VS-Versions.

Usually the files are installed in the Windows\System32 directory for 64bit. So lookup the file you need and search for (i.e. MFC140u.dll) and you can determine it's version.

Also some programs may have a local copy of the runtime DLLs in their application directory...

Comment: *"Also some programs may have a local copy of the runtime DLLs in their application directory..."* - Not some, but **all** properly deployed applications have local copies of their dependencies in their application directory.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve written an application that inspects the customer installation.  It works somewhat like the Microsoft Troubleshooters in that it identifies certain information about the user installation so that our tech support people can identify a potential problem with the customer installation.  One of the things it reports on is the VC redistributables that are installed.
I accomplish this by interrogating the following **LOCAL MACHINE** registry key:

```
SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall
```

The code iterates through the sub-keys looking for a match on the “DisplayName” attribute of each sub-key.  I look for “Microsoft”, “Visual”, “C++”, and “Redistributable”.  If **all** strings are found, I collect the “DisplayVersion” attribute and report it to a dialog.

While this scheme will not indicate the "current" version, it should provide access to **all** versions that are installed.